# C# [DEV] Developer Tag in Unity

Tags: c#

I’m trying to make Multiplayer FPS game in unity and i want to have Developer tag [DEV]. I want people to see that I’m game [DEV] of the game. What is the code?

[image: Dev tag]

Comment: Sounds like you should edit your question to include more details about how you've set up your game and how your user authentication works, then we can re-open it for answers.

Comment: @DMGregory I did change question

Comment: Again, we'll need to know details of how your players authenticate in your game in order to tell you how your game can recognize you and only you and mark only your account with the dev tag.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't shown us how you manage player IDs and authentication, we can't show you exactly how to plug this into your current system. But let's assume your player authentication database/API lets you query it with a method a bit like this:

```
public PlayerData GetPlayerData(PlayerID id, AuthenticationToken token);
```

Where `PlayerData` is a database record about a particular player that you can hold in-game as a struct:

```
public struct PlayerData {
    public readonly PlayerID id;
    public readonly string displayName;
    public readonly bool isDeveloper;
    // ... othee player attributes you care about.
}
```

Now when your game client joins a game session, or new players join the session with your client, we can use your authentication service to confirm their identity and download their display information, keeping a local cache of `PlayerData` instances for the players in this session.

When creating the display string for a player's name to appear in the UI, you can check the `isDeveloper` flag to render it appropriately:

```
public string FormatDisplayName(PlayerData data, string teamColor) {

    if(data.isDeveloper == false)
        return string.Format("<color={0}>{1}</color>", teamColor, data.displayName);

    return string.Format("<color=#ffff00>[DEV]</color><color={0}>{1}</color>", teamColor, data.displayName);
}
```

This lets only those players tagged with `isDeveloper = true` in your player database appear with the [DEV] tag in its own colour. All other players will just show their display name in their team's colour.

Since the data is stored server-side, you have full control over which accounts you tag as developers, so you can confer or revoke the tag without updating any hard-coded info in the game executable. A player could hack their local client to display other users as [DEV], but this wouldn't affect the experience of players running unhacked versions, since the client does not have authority to tell other clients "I'm a dev!" — only your trusted server shares this info.